# Unique challenge of s3 Bucket Policy for 'Grant/Restrictions' access

Tags: permissions, amazon-s3, policy, sql-grant, bucket

I read the directions for posting, so I will be as specific as possible.

I have an S3 bucket with numerous FLV files that I will be allowing customers to stream on THEIR domains.

What I am trying to accomplish is

1. Setting a bucket policy that 'GRANTS' access to specific domains (a list) to stream my bucket files from their domains.
2. A bucket policy that restricts a user to 'one stream' per domain. In other words, for each domain listed in the above policy, they can only stream one file at a time on their site.

The premise is a video site where customers will be streaming videos specific to their niche. I make host and deliver the videos, but need some control over their delivery.

All files are in ONE bucket. There aren't any weird things going on with the files. It's very straight forward.

I just need the bucket policy control that would Grant and also Restrict the ability of my customers to stream my content from their domains.

I PRAY I have been clear enough, but please don't hesitate to ask if I have confused you...

Thanks VERY much
A

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can achieve what you want by simply setting access permissions to the bucket.
I checked in AccessControlList and CannedAccessControlList.
Your best bet will be to write a webservice wrapper to access the bucket data.
You will have better control over the data you serve and may be you might also explore the option of cached copy of data for higher optimization.

Comment: That sounds awfully complex. Am I correct in the initial consideration of grating access to a list of domains? This seems rather direct through policies. It seems what you are saying is that to accomplish the second part (restricting the number of times a domain CAN stream a file) is the more complex part of the equation?